# reference of array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have the following code

```
char str[] = "some string"; // legal
char const* str2 = str;     // legal
char const** str3 = &str2;  // legal
char const** str4 = &str;   // illegal (error: cannot convert 'char (*)[12]' to 'const char (*)[]' in initialization )
```

Why the last one is not compiled? What is the type of `&str`?

Comment: what is the error given on the last one?

Comment: *Arrays are **not** pointers*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `str` is an array, the type of `&str` is a "pointer to array of 12 `const` `char`". The valid declaration would be:

```
char const (*str4)[12] = &str;
```

The declaration of `str3` works fine because `str2` is a "pointer to `const` `char`", not an array, initialized using array-to-pointer conversion. The same array-to-pointer conversion does not occur when you take the address of an array, as in the declaration of `str4`.

Comment: What can I do something to adapt this declaration for array of any length? For example, I tried `char const (*str4)[]` and I got an error.

Comment: @user14416 You can't - it's a pointer to an array of specific length.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the number of de-referencings. (str[] or str*) -> data, str2 -> data, str3 -> pointer(str2) -> data, str4 -> pointer -> data. The number of * simbols tells you home many imes you need to dereference it to get to the data. Each time is jumping from address to address and only the last access is asctually data.

The right way would be:

```
char const* str4 = &str; //or
char const* str4 = str2;
```